# Access 13 Switchboard Displays Wrong Title

Tags: ms-access, title

I have used the switchboard manager of Access 2013 to create a switchboard to navigate to my forms and reports. I have created a total of 5 switchboards to categorize the different types of report.

The problem is that none of the switchboard's titles (except one) shows the name of the switchboard. Rather it shows the name of one of the items in the switchboard. Also, changing the order of the items changes the title to another item in the switchboard in a random order.

Example:

[image: screenshot of switchboard form]

Here the name of the switchboard is "Reports", but the title says "Employee Information", the name of the 4th point.

Comment: can you provide some code? screenshot?

Comment: http://i58.tinypic.com/263bkp3.png Here the name of the switchboard is "Reports" But the title says "Employee Information", the name of the 4th point.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer: Make a copy of your database before you start playing around with this**

Open the table "Switchboard Items" that was auto-created to help manage the switchboard.

I made a switchboard with 3 pages. My Switchboard Items table looks like the screenshot below. I've put a red rectangle around each of the 3 switchboards and their related items:

[image]

It looks as though the records where ItemNumber = 0 include the title for that switchboard in the ItemText field (highlighted in yellow above).

Try editing the ItemText for the records that have an ItemNumber = 0 to what you want the title to be. Then re-open your switchboards to see if it has fixed it.

Comment: Nope... for the switchboard i gave above, the fields with itemNumber 0 has itemtext "Report". yet it shows Employee Information, whose itemNumber is 4.

Comment: I found a solution, reversed the positions (i.e. changed the row) where they lie, and now all of them shows the correct name. It seems their name depends on the position on the row...

Answer (score 0):

The switchboard titles are changed at runtime by `SetProperty` embedded macros run in the Switchboard form `OnOpen` event, and by the `OnClick` event of the Option1 button in the Switchboard form Detail section. These `SetProperty` macros set the Caption property of the `Label1` and `Label2` controls in the form header section based on the result of a DLookup query on the Switchboard Items table.

The criteria for this query needs to be more restrictive to include the `ItemNumber` field in addition to the `SwitchboardID` field. Change the value of this `SetProperty` macro

```
From: =DLookup("ItemText","Switchboard Items","SwitchboardID]=" & [TempVars]("SwitchboardID"))

To: =DLookup("ItemText","Switchboard Items","SwitchboardID]=" & [TempVars]("SwitchboardID") & " And [ItemNumber]=0")
```

In the `OnClick` embedded macro for the Option1 button make these changes only in the `If [Command]=1` section.

This answer applies to Access 16 and probably earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I've met same error. Some net searching shows this error was already mentioned in 2007. Probably even earlier.
As dlookup ignores indexing in the "Switchboard Items" table, probably editing of dlookup formula is the best solution.